# What is the best way to implement the function(String) -> Set<String>?

Tags: ios, swift, set

You must implement a function that meets the following requirements:

- Returns: 10 product names containing the specified string.
  If there are several products with the same name, producer's name is added to product's name in the format " - ",
  otherwise returns simply "".
  */

`func listProductsByName(searchString: String) -> Set<String>`

You cannot use error handling, so I thought to fill the Set with default data, but this solution does not work. What is the best way to implement this function?

```
func listProductsByName(searchString: String) -> Set<String> {
    
    var searchProducts = Set<String>()
    
    for product in products {
        if product.name.contains(searchString) {
            if !searchProducts.contains(product.name){
                searchProducts.insert(product.name)}
            else { searchProducts.insert(product.name + " - " + product.producer)}
            }
        if searchProducts.count == 10 {
            break
        }
    }
    
    if searchProducts.count < 10 {
        var emptyElement = 0
        print("Найдено меньше 10 товаров: \(searchProducts)")
        repeat {
            searchProducts.insert("Пустой элемент № \(emptyElement)")
            emptyElement += 1
        } while searchProducts.count < 10
    }

    return searchProducts
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the challenge literally do the following steps.

- `filter` products which name contains the search string and get the first 10 items by `prefix(10)`
- Group the array to a dictionary `[String:[Product]]` by the product name. That's the most efficient way to identify products with the same name.
- Now insert the names. If the product name is unique (there is only one product) insert the name. If not `map` the names by adding the producer.

  ```
  func listProductsByName(searchString: String) -> Set<String> {

       var searchProducts = Set<String>()
       let filteredProducts = products
          .filter{$0.name.localizedStandardContains(searchString)}
          .prefix(10)

       let groupedFilteredProducts = Dictionary(grouping: filteredProducts, by: \.name)
       for (name, products) in groupedFilteredProducts {
           if products.count == 1 {
               searchProducts.insert(name)
           } else {
               searchProducts.union(Set(products.map{$0.name + " - " + $0.producer}))
           }
       }
       return searchProducts
   }
  ```